# Angular 2 CLI : Need to install xml2json package

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Being new to angular 2 i am trying to install xml2json package but getting some error. I have tried similar questions posted but nothing helped me

below are things i have installed
1) node latest version
2) python 2 ... also set env variables
3) npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
4) npm install node-gyp

but still i get error. is there any sequence do i need to follow to get xml2json installed

```js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "xml2json"
npm ERR! node v7.7.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Angular2\XML2JS\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you trying to install xml2json? or angular 2 CLI ?

Comment: xml2json in angular2 cli project using npm

Comment: is there any other way to use xml2json other than npm

Answer (score 1):

[suggestion]
Since you are using Angular-CLI, it comes already with a xml utility to use out of the box, https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

So you don't need to install anything extra, just make sure you import it properly in your file.

Angular 2 example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
          <page>
            <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
          </page>`;

  ngOnInit() {
    const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    parser.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        // result is your javascript parsed object
        // you can access attribut for example with lodash getters
        this.title = _.first(_.get(result, 'page.title'));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried npm install --global --production windows-build-tools but not working for me .... can you please give me sequence of things to get xml2json installed

Comment: my python version is 2.7.13

Comment: do u have example using var xml2js = require('xml2js');

Comment: I added an angular 2 example

Comment: the documentation has more require examples :) https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js